# Convert form data into storage file in universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Currently i have created a windows universal application to take input from the user and store that data into a form  page, i want to take that data from the page and convert into a PDF file
how can i achieve this?

Comment: Please explain what you have and your problem in more detail. Do you want to save the data into a PDF file or a StorageFile? Can't you just save the data from the user input directly? Does it have to be taken from a form? What does the form do?

Comment: whenever i take the user input and when ever user clicks submit button i have to generate a pdf file with the form data

Comment: Please refer to [Printing sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing), this sample can print document into a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Try Syncfusion, they have library for PDF creation

http://www.syncfusion.com/products/uwp